# How to get access to Gmail in Django

Tags: python, django, oauth

I'm trying to have a page in my webapp with a button 'Connect to Gmail', which sends the user to an authentication page, and when they get back their access token gets saved in my database for later use. I've been literally trying this for weeks, but I can't figure it out. I've tried xoauth, but it seems to only work as a stand-alone script.

Does anyone have some pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is OpenID. Check if some fits your need here:

http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/facebook-authentication/ (I know they write facebook authentication, though this page includes openid solutions and full featured solutions with Facebook/Twitter login as well)

I made good experience with [django-socialregistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration).